# Отсутствует дефолтная кнопка запуска кода в VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Кнопка запуска кода]

Пропала дефолтная кнопка в виде треугольного значка запуска программного кода.
Кнопку RUN-PYTHON-FILE можно найти нажав на три точки справа. Но почему-то эта кнопка не передвигается на то место, где раньше был значок запуска.

Можно конечно через терминал запускать, но мне было удобнее, когда присутствовала кнопка.

Answer (score 0):

Нашла решение. Нужно нажать правой кнопкой мыши на три точки справа в углу и поставить галочки возле Run-Or-Debug.

[image: Как на скриншоте]